Which is the path of the libapp.so in flutter apps?
I'm trying to decompile my own app, build in flutter; as I read here What are libapp.so and libflutter.so? my code should be in libapp.so, but I can't find it, only libflutter.so is present. Is there any setting to do in the build configuration? Is something changed in the midtime?

You can use Android Studio to analyze an apk of Flutter app, then you'll see both libapp.so and libflutter.so there

Open folder /android inside root folder by Android Studio as an Android project (not as a Flutter project)
Menu -> Build -> Analyze APK -> choose your APK


